# C++ what if I don't know array size and need to receive an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a function like:

```
function(double* numbers)
```

I know that if I know the size of the numbers array, I can then do

```
double* numbers = new double[size];
function(numbers)
```

This will return the value in `numbers` correctly, however, now I don't know the size of `numbers`, I still want to use function `function`, which is a third party library function which I don't want to change, is there a way to get the array out without knowing the size of array?

Comment: No there isn't.

Comment: You simply use a `std::vector<double>` instead of a raw pointer.

Comment: It depends entirely on what `function` does with the variable and the contract it provides.

Comment: Only the 3rd party library will know, how it communicates the array length. Since it doesn't appear to take an explicit length argument, the array must be either implied, or terminated by some sentinel value.

Comment: @Rusheng Zhang A function declared like this function(double* numbers) knows nothing about the size of the array used as an argument. So you should not bother about this because the function itself does not bother about this.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow so how do I retrieve this value?

Comment: @RushengZhang Why do you bother about the function that you did not write?:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow This function returns an array to the variable numbers which I need to pass into and retrieve the value. So I'll have to need to pass something there and get the value. The standard way is to pass a double* numbers = new double[size]; into the function but now I don't know the size.

Comment: @RushengZhang One more you should not bother how the function processes arrays passed to it. Just read the description of the function and call it accordingly its description. It is not your problem. It is a problem of the author of the library where the function is called from.

Comment: A workable technique would be to reserve element 0 of the array as the array size.  I don't like it.  jotiks suggestion is much better.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no standard way to retrieve the size of the array at run time from a mere pointer. I suggest you either use `std::array` for fixed-size arrays, or `std::vector` for variable-length arrays. An less safe alternative would be to pass the size of the array together with the pointer.